# How to handle SEH exception in the SafeFileHandle finalizer?

Tags: c#, .net

I see that on some environments, `SafeFileHandle`'s finalizer throw a `SEHException` because the finalizer is trying to close an already closed handle.

The issue is that `SEHException` must be thrown ONLY if the debugger is connected. 
In other cases, it should just do nothing for the `CloseHandle` API.

But without any debuggers on clean envs (no antiviruses, VS or something like that), we are observing such problem. Looks like a .NET or Windows bug.

I see one solution - write a custom `SafeFileHandle` that will handle the `SEHException` in dispose. But I need to refactor the huge project and replace all `SafeFileHandles`.

Is there any way `UnhandledException` handler to swallow this exception or abort the thread that is causing it (`GC` finilizer thread)? Any ideas?

Comment: As far as exceptions go, this is a freakin' nasty problem.  The kind you can never wish away by just assuming it is a CLR or OS bug.  Only memory corruption can ever provide a simple explanation.  Or the one thing that SafeHandle protects against, a handle recycle attack launched by malware.  Get a minidump, call Microsoft Support.

Comment: If you got exceptions, there are 99.9% chance that your code is wrong... **Clearly, if you close an handle that is already closed, then your code have a bug**. So you should fix unbalanced open/close. It might also be helpful to write your own code to manage opening and closing if you application is complex and a file can be opened or close at different time particulary if multithreading or multiple event handlers might cause concurrent use of the same file.

Comment: @Phil1970  I am not closing an handle that is already closed. Net framework is calling finilizer for the file that is closed! (state of handle = 3  - Closed). And it is not closed by me with native CloseHandle call because in such case handle state will not be = 3(closed).  I can't make syncronization of .NET GC and synchronize GC with my code! And I got SEHException that is invalid without debugger.